# Which hosts have low latency across United States and Europe?

Tags: web-hosting, latency

I'm looking for some information on web hosts that have low latency (<100ms) to both the United States and Europe.

- The host can be in either the United States or Europe.
- Latency is most important to the United States, United Kingdom, the Netherlands, Sweden and Norway.
- Should be able to provide managed hosting.
- Hosting at multiple locations is not what I'm looking for.

Answers should contain at least some latency information from multiple locations, preferably from Los Angeles, New York, London, Amsterdam and Oslo. Also some information on your experience with this host is preferred, do not rant, do provide details of your package (with or without SLA, dedicated or VPS etc.).

From my own little research I found that probably New York based hosts can offer low latency to all these locations, but I do not have much statistics to back that up other than my own ping is about 85ms to New York from the Netherlands.

Comment: You aer awaer that this host would have to be somewhere in between? That is abotu the only way to get low ping times into both sides. Greenland has a data center (like in: ONE) that offers colocation and hosting ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using http://just-ping.com/ and ping machines in some datacenters to get more scientific latency figures. And yes, New York is the best location for your server.

Comment: You're right this helps a lot